# Catching multiple events from guava eventbus

Tags: guava, event-bus

i would like to catch multiple events in case to run some method with several arguments. Is there possibility to achieve that without writing own dispatcher that will glue my events together?

Comment: i can remove that swing tag if you want??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `EventBus` itself directly dispatches events to listeners. It has no knowledge of how your various events relate to each other, how to glue them, when to stop, etc.

You can do that in a listener subcribed to the various needed events, though, but I guess that's what you call "writing your own dispatcher". Someone has to write it at some point.